# Creating customer form list array which can be clicked on to edit or delete

Tags: arrays, angular, list, forms, angular-ngmodel

im currently working on a small task which is essentially a customer form where users can submit data and the data is then stored in an array and presented as a list.

I have managed to complete the form and i can submit data into an array and output it into a list. i am know trying to figure out how i can then click on the data in the list and have the data re-populate the fields in the form and for me then to  edit or delete.

i have searched online for "clickable lists" and "actionable lists" but there doesnt seem to be anything i can use as it is all static. i have seen someone use a button in the list but that also doesnt work as all my data is then added to one big button. i have come across material UI but i would prefer to do it without using a library.

i have attached my code below:

contacts.component.html:

````
    <!-- <p>contacts works!</p> -->

    <div class="main">
        <!-- <input type="text" class="inputSearch" placeholder="search"> -->
        <label for="name" class="nameLbl">Name</label>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let contact of contacts">{{contact.firstName}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <form #add="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addContact(add) ; add.resetForm()">


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">First Name</label>
            <input class="inpt" type="text" id="text" name="firstName" ngModel />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Last Name</label>
            <input class="inpt" type="text" id="text" name="lastName" ngModel />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Email</label>
            <input class="inpt" type="email" id="text" name="email" ngModel />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Address 1</label>
            <input class="inpt" type="text" id="text" name="address1" ngModel />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Address 2</label>
            <input class="inpt" type="text" id="text" name="address2" ngModel />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">City</label>
            <input class="inpt" type="text" id="text" name="city" ngModel />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">PostCode</label>
            <input class="inpt" type="text" id="text" name="postcode" ngModel />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="text">Telephone</label>
            <input class="inpt" type="number" id="text" name="telephone" ngModel />
        </div>

        <br>
        <button class="addContactBtn">Add Contact</button>
    </form>

</div>```


contacts.component.ts:

    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-contacts',
      templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css']
    })
    export class ContactsComponent {
    
      contacts: any = []
    
    
    
      addContact(add: any) {
        console.log("Contact Added", add);
        this.contacts.push(add.value)
        console.log(this.contacts);
        
      }
    
    
    }
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

import { emailValidator } from './email-validator.directive';

interface Contact {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  address1: string;
  address2: string;
  city: string;
  zipCode: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  fg!: FormGroup;

  contacts: Contact[] = [
    {
      firstName: 'Test',
      lastName: 'Test',
      email: 't@tt.com',
      address1: 'test',
      address2: 'test',
      city: 'test',
      zipCode: '123',
    },
  ];

  get firstNameField(): FormControl {
    return this.fg.get('firstName') as FormControl;
  }

  get lastNameField(): FormControl {
    return this.fg.get('lastName') as FormControl;
  }

  get emailField(): FormControl {
    return this.fg.get('email') as FormControl;
  }

  get address1Field(): FormControl {
    return this.fg.get('address1') as FormControl;
  }

  get address2Field(): FormControl {
    return this.fg.get('address2') as FormControl;
  }

  get zipCodeField(): FormControl {
    return this.fg.get('zipCode') as FormControl;
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
  }

  initForm(): void {
    this.fg = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      lastName: ['', [Validators.required]],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      address1: ['', [Validators.required]],
      address2: ['', [Validators.required]],
      city: ['', [Validators.required]],
      zipCode: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  saveContact(): void {
    console.log(this.fg);
    if (this.fg.valid) {
      this.contacts.push(this.fg.value);
      this.fg.reset();
    }
  }

  edit(index: number): void {
    const data = this.contacts[index];
    this.fg.patchValue(data);
  }

  delete(index: number): void {
    this.contacts.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

> app.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="fg">
  <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName="firstName"
    placeholder="First Name"
  />

  <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName="lastName"
    placeholder="Last Name"
  />

  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input
    type="email"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName="email"
    placeholder="Email"
  />

  <label for="address1">Address1:</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName="address1"
    placeholder="Address1"
  />

  <label for="address2">Address2:</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName="address2"
    placeholder="Address2"
  />

  <label for="address2">City:</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName="city"
    placeholder="City"
  />

  <label for="address1">Zip Code:</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName="zipCode"
    placeholder="Zip Code"
  />

  <button (click)="saveContact()">Save</button>
</form>

<div style="padding:1rem">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let contact of contacts; let i = index">
      <p>First Name: {{ contact.firstName }}</p>
      <p>Last Name: {{ contact.lastName }}</p>
      <button (click)="edit(i)">Edit</button>
      <button (click)="delete(i)">Delete</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[the working example is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular13-reactive-form-validation-3n2n32?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: hi, thank you for that. it does seem to work. would you be able to explain what you have actually done to make this work please?

Comment: I added the comments in the stackblitz. Please check and let me know if you need any more information. Refer https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-reactive-forms-introduction

Comment: ive been playing with the code and it seems to work. i was just wondering is there a way to update the one item? so at the moment when you click on update it basically adds a new item to the list, i just want it to update the one value

Comment: yes, you can. Before pushing the form value to the contacts array you will check array already have that contact or not if the array has that contact then get the index of that item and update those values in that array by using that index.

Comment: ive tried to work on it and it doesnt seem to work. i understand the logic to say if this  user already exists just change the data for this index. but im not sure how to implement it

Comment: @lunaar I updated my stackblitz. Please check and let me know.